# Want My Screenshot To Display In A JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, screenshot, jlabel

I have a program that takes a screenshot when a JButton is pressed, but for some reason it wont show in my JFrame. I know that the method works because the JFrame re-sizes like I tell it to but for some reason it wont display the shot.

**CODE**

```
public class main implements ActionListener{
public static Font f = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 25);
static JButton button = new JButton("Press For A Screen Shot!");
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Snipping Tool+");
static JLabel label;
static Graphics2D g2d;
static JPanel panel;
BufferedImage shot;

public main(){

    frame.setSize(400, 350);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    button.setFont(f);
    button.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    button.setForeground(Color.white);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
```

I have my action right here.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
              System.out.println("sh");       
            try {
                shot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new          
Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            } catch (HeadlessException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }               
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            frame.setSize(screenSize);
            Image ii = (BufferedImage) shot;
            g2d.drawImage(shot, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING, 0, 0, 0, null);
        }
    });      

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("res//images//SnippingTool.png");
    label = new JLabel(image);
    frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    main m = new main();

}
```

This doesn't do anything.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Where are you initializing/getting your `Graphics2D g2d` object from?

Comment: @Jeff at the top i do static Graphics2D g2d;

Comment: The program isn't throwing a NPE, so it must be initialized somewhere, with a getGraphics() method. However, as a general rule, you should never use the getGraphics() method.

Comment: @DilanHanrahan And you're initializing it to `null`.

Comment: @DilanHanrahan That's not initializing the object.  That's just creating a null reference.

Comment: @Jeff how about `static Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) frame.getGraphics();`

Comment: Don't worry about the Graphics objects. That is not the proper way to solve the problem. Remove the Graphics object and deal with the real issue. The easiest solution is to display the image in a JLabel, the other option is to use custom painting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Graphics.drawImage(...) method should only be invoked from withing a painting method, like the paintComponent() method of a class that does custom painting. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

The easiest solution is to create an ImageIcon using the image and then just set the Icon of a JLabel that you have added to your frame. Then the label will repaint itself automatically.

Also, don't use static variables. Again use the examples from the tutorial to better structure your program.

Comment: how to I change the bufferedImage to a ImageIcon?

Comment: Read the ImageIcon API. Or read the Swing tutorial on `How to Use Icons`. You can find this tutorial by getting the table of contents from the previous tutorial link.